# If f/g is symmetric (resp homogeneous), must f and g be as well?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, rational-functions

Suppose we have two polynomials $f$, $g$ in $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$ over some field $k$, and they have no factor in common. Suppose that $f/g$ is symmetric. Must than $f$ and $g$ also both be symmetric?

Same question for homogeneous instead of symmetric.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I'm afraid that in this case $f,g$ will share a factor $X_1-X_2$.

Comment: @Wojowu, how is that the case ($f, g$ share a common factor of $X_1 - X_2$)? I'm just having trouble answering this question.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Someone else gave a "counterexample" $f=x^2-y^2,g=x-y$ (iirc) to OPs statement. However, the two polynomials share a factor in this case, so it's no counterexample.

Comment: But why do they share a factor?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Because $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So with that and your last comment, $f$ and $g$ share a common factor $x - y$.

Comment: I'm assuming that the field $k$ is finite. Am I right? Maybe it is, because it says so.